# React Leaflet Polyline with arrow Head Issues

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

I am using react Leaflet. I try to implement it with a polyline with an arrowhead.

it showing the following error.

> 1.TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined at t.n.componentDidMount (MapLayer.js:40)
> 2.TypeError: Cannot read property 'leafletElement' of undefined at a.value (Polyline.js:8)
> 3.TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeLayer' of undefined at t.n.componentWillUnmount (MapLayer.js:61)

here I add my Maplayer.js and Polyline.js also

**MapLayer.js**

```
import type { Layer } from 'leaflet'
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'

import { LeafletProvider } from './context'
import MapComponent from './MapComponent'
import type { LeafletContext, MapLayerProps } from './types'

export default class MapLayer<LeafletElement: Layer,Props: MapLayerProps,>     
extends MapComponent<LeafletElement, Props> {
  contextValue: ?LeafletContext
   leafletElement: LeafletElement

 constructor(props: Props) {
 super(props)
 this.leafletElement = this.createLeafletElement(props)
}


get layerContainer(): Layer {
return this.props.leaflet.layerContainer || this.props.leaflet.map
 }

createLeafletElement(_props: Props): LeafletElement {
 throw new Error('createLeafletElement() must be implemented')
}

updateLeafletElement(_fromProps: Props, _toProps: Props) {}

componentDidMount() {
super.componentDidMount()
this.layerContainer.addLayer(this.leafletElement)
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Props) {
super.componentDidUpdate(prevProps)

if (this.props.attribution !== prevProps.attribution) {
  const { map } = this.props.leaflet
  if (map != null && map.attributionControl != null) {
    map.attributionControl.removeAttribution(prevProps.attribution)
    map.attributionControl.addAttribution(this.props.attribution)
  }
}

this.updateLeafletElement(prevProps, this.props)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
super.componentWillUnmount()
this.layerContainer.removeLayer(this.leafletElement)
}

 render() {
  const { children } = this.props
  if (children == null) {
   return null
 }
  return this.contextValue == null ? (
  <Fragment>{children}</Fragment>
   ) : (
  <LeafletProvider value={this.contextValue}>{children}</LeafletProvider>
  )
  }
 }
```

**Polyline.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Polyline } from 'react-leaflet'
import 'leaflet-arrowheads'

class ArrowheadsPolyline extends React. Component{

 componentDidMount(){
  const polyline = this.polylineRef.leafletElement
  if (this.props.arrowheads){
     polyline.arrowheads(this.props.arrowheads)
     polyline._update()
  }
 }
 componentWillUnmount(){
  if (this.props.arrowheads){
     const polyline = this.polylineRef.leafletElement
     polyline.deleteArrowheads()
  }
  }
  render(){
  return(
     <Polyline {...this.props} ref={polylineRef => this.polylineRef = polylineRef} />
  )
  }

}


export default ArrowheadsPolyline
```

and my map component is like

```
<Map <Polyline positions={ [coordinates] } arrowheads /> />
```

If you guys have any idea please let me know